# Xcode 8.1 release APP crash libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, ios9.1, xcode8

APP in Xcode8.1 directly installed on the phone to run on all versions are not any problems, posted .ipa to the Third-party platforms installed,in iOS9.3 the following does not have any problem, but when I submitted to AppStore and testfight installed to the phone in iOS9.3 The following version will be an exception flashback, any one encountered the same problem Yeah, solving, I have not encountered in the use of Xcode7 published this problem.

Could anyone advise how I may be able to track this down?

I am getting the crash shown below in Crashlytics.

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 28
1 libobjc.A.dylib   (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508
2 FrontBoardServices    -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
3 FrontBoardServices    -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
4 CoreFoundation    ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
5 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
6 CoreFoundation    ___CFRunLoopRun + 724
7 CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
8 UIKit -[UIApplication _run] + 460
9 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 204
10 huxijia  main (main.m:14)
11 libdyld.dylib    _start + 4



0   libobjc.A.dylib
objc_msgSend + 28
1   CoreFoundation
CFEqual + 340
2   CoreFoundation
___NSCacheKeyEqual + 12
3   libcache.dylib
__entry_get_optionally_checking_collisions + 164
4   libcache.dylib
cache_get_and_retain + 132
5   CoreFoundation
-[NSCache objectForKey:] + 68
6   CoreUI
-[CUIStructuredThemeStore _canGetRenditionWithKey:isFPO:lookForSubstitutions:] + 360
7   CoreUI
-[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 1416
8   CoreUI
-[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 148
9   UIKit
___98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424
10  UIKit
-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 212
11  UIKit
-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:withTrait:] + 528
12  UIKit
__UIImageWithNameAndTraitCollection + 96
13  UIKit
+[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _kitImageNamed:withTrait:] + 36
14  UIKit
_CreateScrollIndicator + 260
15  UIKit
-[UIScrollView _adjustScrollerIndicators:alwaysShowingThem:] + 200
16  UIKit
-[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 524
17  UIKit
-[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 300
18  UIKit
-[UIPickerTableView _setContentOffset:notify:] + 100
19  UIKit
-[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary] + 60


0   libobjc.A.dylib
objc_msgSend + 28
1   libcache.dylib
__entry_get_optionally_checking_collisions + 52
2   libcache.dylib
__entry_table_resize + 308
3   libcache.dylib
cache_set_and_retain + 852
4   CoreFoundation
-[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:] + 268
5   CoreUI
-[CUIStructuredThemeStore _canGetRenditionWithKey:isFPO:lookForSubstitutions:] + 860
6   CoreUI
-[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 924
7   CoreUI
-[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 148
8   UIKit
___98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424
9   UIKit
-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 260
10  UIKit
-[UIImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 404
11  UIKit
-[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:] + 460
12  UIKit
-[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 212
13  UIKit
-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760
14  UIKit
-[UIActivityIndicatorView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 196
15  UIKit
-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760
16  UIKit
-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760
17  UIKit
-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760
18  UIKit
___45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152
19  UIKit
-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504
```

Answer (score 1):

Crashes in ObjC runtime and/or autorelease operations are almost always a dangling pointer.

I highly doubt this is related to the environment. More like, there's just a code path/edge case that you aren't seeing during normal development. I'd start with NSZombies, which can be really helpful.

I'd also recommend looking through your Crashlytics crashes for strange unrecognized selector crashes, or other things in runtime code. They could all potentially be related to the same underlying root cause.